# How to get IAM encoded authorization message when cloudtrail cuts off at 1028 characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudtrail

I'm getting an IAM error and trying to understand which action is being denied.

In my Cloudtrail event, the encoded authorization failure message cuts off at 1028 characters

```json
{
    "errorCode": "Client.UnauthorizedOperation",
    "errorMessage": "You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: SuperLongMessageThatEndsWith...",
}
```

How can I get the full encoded authorization message?

Comment: Are you not getting whole message or looking for decoding of message like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-not-auth-launch/)?

Comment: Not getting the whole message. Cloudtrail events look to have a 1028 character limit. Trying to get the full message so I can decode using `aws sts decode-authorization-message`

Comment: Those authorization messages typically just tell you the user identity, resource, and name of the operation invoked. All of which is available from other sources in the CloudTrail event.

Comment: The authorization message will also tell you whether the auth error was due to an explicit deny, and which SID in the policy statement denied it (none of which is available in the cloudtrail event details)

Comment: @maafk Did you ever happen to find a solution to this? I fear Michael's answer below is the best that can be done, but I live in hope!

Comment: Amazon should reorder the cloudtrail message if an encoded message is included to just include that at the very least. This issue kills me, I very rarely interact with someone who's having an issue that will supply that information upfront; instead, I need to waste time having them recreate the issue and supply the encoded string to me in the proper format so I can decode it.

Answer (score 3):

If the content is over 1 KB, it is truncated. From the AWS documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-record-contents.html

> **errorCode** The AWS service error if the request returns an error. For
> an example that shows this field, see Error code and message log
> example. This field has a maximum size of 1 KB; content exceeding that
> limit is truncated.

Answer (score -3):

I am assuming you have already tried to run the command on CLI to decode the message.

Have a look at this support page
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aws-backup-encoded-authorization-failure/

I just saw the post is 3 months old, but I just came across it today. Hoping it is useful

Comment: The issue I'm running into is that the _encoded_ message is cut off, so I'm not able to do the cli command `aws sts decode-authorization-message`.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Or, now knowing that your post does not help OP, please delete it.